# Jekyll output collection list organized by tag

Tags: collections, tags, jekyll

I'm having trouble grouping items by tags in a collection. I've managed to do it with site.categories (check bellow), but i'm having trouble fecthing yaml attributes from collection items in the same way.

```
{% for imagens in site.imagens %}
 <div class="card">
  <ul class="lista-imagens">
   <li><a class="categories" name="{{ imagens.tags | first }}">{ {{     imagens.tags | first }} }</a>
  <ul >
   <li>
    <img src="{{ imagens.image_path }}" alt="{{ imagens.title }}">
    <a href="{{ imagens.original_path }}" target="_blank">{{ imagens.title }}</a>
    <span class="ano">{{ imagens.year }}</span>
    </li>   
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
{% endfor %}


{% for category in site.categories %}
<div class="col-md-3">
 <ul class="listinha">
<li><a class="categories" name="{{ category | first }}">{ {{ category | first }} }</a>
  <ul >
  {% for posts in category %}
    {% for post in posts %}
      <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>  <br>
      <span class="autor"> {{ post.author }} {% if post.year %}<br> {{ post.year }} {% endif %} </span><span class="contributor">{{ post.contributor }} <!-- / imgs: {{ post.imgs }}<br>--></span></li>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What is the part that it isn't working and what would be the desired output?

Comment: Well, this is what i get https://mentes-desertas.github.io/imagens-lista.html, and this is what I would like to have https://mentes-desertas.github.io/imagens.html (this page was made just with html)